# Remove all records with duplicates in db2. (Not just the duplicate records)

Tags: db2, duplicates, delete-row

How can I remove all the records with duplicates in db2. I have looked at various answers but they only remove the duplicates leaving one record from that set in the table. This is what I found already.

DELETE FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ONE, TWO, THREE) AS RN
     FROM SESSION.TEST) AS A
WHERE RN > 1;

But, I need a query that will remove all the records that contain duplicates not leaving behind one of them in the table.

A      A       1  <-- delete this
 A      A       2  <-- delete this too
 B      B       3
 C      C       4

P.S: Using RN >= 1 does not work as it will make the table empty by deleting all records.

Answer (score 0):

Your original statement wouldn't work in any case - it would only delete anything *after* the after row (and given you seem to list the unique id column in the `PARTITION BY`, shouldn't actually delete anything at all).

The following should work in LUW:

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3
             FROM <tableName> ot
             JOIN (SELECT col1, col2
                   FROM <tableName>
                   GROUP BY col1, col2
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dt
               ON dt.col1 = ot.col1
                  AND dt.col2 = ot.col2)
```

(although I have no way to test this)

I believe the following should also work, and be near universal (work on most RDBMSs):

```
DELETE FROM Temp
WHERE (col1, col2) IN (SELECT col1, col2
                       FROM Temp
                       GROUP BY col1, col2
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ddf2a/3/1)</kbd>